# Are dialers obsolete?

Tags: malware, phone, risk-analysis

My antivirus picked up an infection by Dialer/Coulomb. The definition of a dialer is a piece of malware that dials a number that charges money. How would it do this, is this from when modems were connected to the phone lines? Can this still happen if the computer is connected through wi-fi to a cable modem?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a modem attached to a phone line then the "dialer" is harmless, but nothing tells you that it's only a dialer and not a general-purpose rootkit/remote administration tool.

Note that mobile broadband cards (either as external USB devices or built-in) still appear as a modem and most of them can do phone calls, so if you have mobile broadband then it may still use your mobile subscription to call the number (which may be even worse because calls from mobile are usually more expensive).

Better safe than sorry, so my advice is to follow [this guide](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** this crapware is coming from the time where many user were still connected to the Internet through a **dialup modem**, i.e. a modem able to make a call on the phone line through plain old `at...` modem commands.
If you have an USB key which provides a modem interface,
if your mobile phone is connected through Bluetooth and provides a modem interface directly accessible from Windows,
then this crapware will be able to dial through this modem interface.

**No** this crapware can't do anything on a **cable modem** or an **ADSL modem** on the phone line (but which doesn't provide any interface to send it any `at...` command).

Comment: A cable modem (which connects to your cable line) is not the same thing as an ADSL modem (which connects to your phone line).

Comment: Right, fixed. From what I read, I had the false impression that for a lot of people the differences between "not POTS" modems wasn't that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Dialers still work on the Plain Old Telephone System. If the software can access a modem that is connected to a phone line then it can do its thing.

Cable modems do not usually connect over the POTS system and so I would not worry about seeing large toll charges appearing on your bill.

I do from time to time see the occasional large bill from dialers though.